# XSLT diffrence in stylesheets

Tags: xml, xslt

[in my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665194/return-without-xml-root)  i thought i have problem with the XML but there wasn't such a big difference.

i think the problem in the XSL in fact, is there away to know how to bind my XSL stylesheet by the XML or maybe to create XSL that can work with a lot of XML types?

how should my stylesheet suppose to look if thats my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfParticipantEvent xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Accounts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ParticipantEvent>
      <PublicProfile>
        <AccountID>323877</AccountID>
        <PhotoID>6429</PhotoID>
      </PublicProfile>
   </ParticipantEvent>
</ArrayOfParticipantEvent>
```

i just can see all the data of my XML in text on the screen like it ignore the XSL file.

Comment: You forgot to explain what are the requirements for the transformation and to provide the final wanted result. Please, edit the question and correct.

Comment: If you are going to refer to a previous question, please link to it so we can see the previous question.

Comment: i just can see all the data of my xml in txt on the screen like it ignore the xsl file.

Comment: @user1194088, where is your SAMPLE XSL code? pls post **sample** not the real-one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some debuging i found that this line in the xml made that problam with transform the xml:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Accounts"
```

you can see this line in the xml above.

but still i dont know if the problam is in the xml or the xsl but to solve this issue just need to clear the namespace in DataContract like that:

```
 [DataContract(Namespace="")]
```